# Chart.js - Synchronized Charts

Tags: chart.js, synchronized

I am looking charts like below in Chart.js library

http://plottablejs.org/examples/synchronized/
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Comment: check these examples https://github.com/programster/plottable-examples

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a plugin for Chart.js called "chartjs-plugin-crosshair". Look at the "Linked Charts" example here https://chartjs-plugin-crosshair.netlify.app/samples/